# wordpress.mydomian.com 404 Error

Tags: multisite, nginx

I have had configured LEMP stack on my vps and set my "A" records to the server's IP address(v4). mydomin.com works pretty well as well as portfolio.mydomian.com in which I used just CSS and JS and indexed with *.html indexing. But on my blog part I have had use blog.mydomian.com and I configured it very well. and there is no error from NGNIX side, but wenn I try to open wordpress with blog.mydomain.com it returns the 404 Error.
Does anybody here had same experience before, who may help me to solve ?
I will share my mydomian.conf inside /etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomian.com here.
thanks in advance

```
   server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/mydmoain.com/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    access_log /var/www/mydmoain.com/access.log;

    server_name mydmoain.com www.mydmoain.com;

    location / {
           # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
            root /var/www/portfolio.mydmoain.com/public_html;
            index index.html index.htm;
    }

    server_name portfolio.mydmoain.com;
    access_log /var/www/portfolio.mydmoain.com/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/portfolio.mydmoain.com/error.log;

}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
            root /var/www/blog.mydmoain.com/public_html; 
            index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }

   location ~ /\.ht {
             deny all;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;        }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
             expires max;
             log_not_found off;
    }

    server_name blog.mydmoain.com;
    access_log /var/www/blog.mydmoain.com/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/blog.mydmoain.com/error.log;
```

}

Comment: Your `root` directive is in the wrong place. It needs to be within the `server` block so that it is inherited by all location blocks. At the moment, any file ending with `.php` will not be found.

Comment: Hey @RichardSmith

I have tried what you mentioned and it absolutely works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the root directive to server block and it works pretty well, special thanks to @RichardSmith, who have had mentioned the problem.
in case someone has the same Problem I will write a short explanation code.

```
server {
       listen 80;
       root /var/www/blog.mydomian.com
       server_name blog.mydomian.com www.blog.mydomian.com
       # the rest of configuration
}
```